# AngularJS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new in JavaScript. I have learn the basic of java scripts. My next thing to do is to learn JS Framework. I want to learn AngularJS. I have read that if you came from jQuery you will be confuse in learning AngularJS. Do I need to learn jQuery or just AngularJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: No, you do not need to know jQuery to learn Angular, in fact, you'll likely having an easier time learning Angular without intricate knowledge of jQuery.  The only part of jQuery that might help you in learning Angular is DOM manipulation, but with the wealth of directives ([AngularStrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/), [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/)) available at this point, you probably won't need to do much DOM manipulation yourself.

[Author AngularJS gives the answer 18:26](http://youtu.be/X0VsStcCCM8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.So everything jQuery can do It can be done in AngularJS? In short they are overlapping technologies?

Comment: They are overlapping but not fully overlapped. there are things that jquery can do which angular don't and vise-versa. But in fact talking in this terms is just wrong. Angular has different targets and architecture.

Comment: More or less what @vittore said.  jQuery is absolutely not needed, but it may make some tasks easier.